# Huge remote interface -> best practices?

Tags: java, interface

I just had this interesting discussion with a colleague of mine.
We have a remote interface which is 2000+ lines of code and has 100+ methods in it.
The implementation of this interface has some logic but also delegated to other interfaces that are related to a certain concern.

I argued we should also split up the remote interface based on concern.
Advantages:
- Separation of concerns
- Just create different endpoint for each interface, client developers should only use interfaces they are interested in
- No "monster interface"
- Eg. security possible per-endpoint

He opposes this, arguing:
- One remote interface is easy for the client developers

I'm wondering what the "general opinion" on this is?
Is it a good practice to create a remote facade which groups all your concerns in one endpoint?

Comment: _One remote interface is easy for the client developers_ This sentence has no sense at all to me... Using `implements Interface1, Interface2, Interface3` is as easy as using `implements MonsterInterface`. And yes, it is better to split interfaces based on concerns. Also, a huge interface may be easier for clients, but it's a lot harder for developers to maintain.

Comment: i'm not sure if this is a question for Stackoverflow... maybe you can be more specific and tell us HOW this interface looks - and how can an interface have 'some logic' in it?

Comment: I have exactly the same problem in one legacy project. Very big interface exposed via RMI and used by multiple different java clients. After split it up and moving to Spring HttpInvoker I feel much easier to support this project. For clients it a bit worse to maintain, because of configuration. Earlier it was one url and one endpoint, now it is one url with ten service endpoint.

Answer (score 0):

If you think in terms of **scalability** and the fact that behind that interface you could end up having multiple services (at least in a SOA architecture) **it is for sure worth splitting into multiple interfaces**.

And let us see why:

1. Indeed as you pointed out you will have separation of concerns
2. You will have a light weight API - developers will end up using only features they need
3. It is easier to implement versioning - it might not be the case now but can be the case in the future
4. Readability and maintainability on your side - smaller interfaces make it easier to debug code and understand what each concern is supposed to do
5. Indeed security/authorization/authentication per endpoint or per remote interface is much easier to implement
6. I am sure that this list can continue but these are just a few I can think of now

And to give you one last argument - ***"the bigger they are the harder they fall"***